# How to solve error 524 A timeout occured, when sending email

Tags: php, wordpress, email, lazy-loading, buddypress

For my website, I need to send an email to all users every time someone posted something on the blog wall (I am using BuddyPress and Youzify).
For that I wrote a function in function.php, but the problem is that I have a lot of users (around 300), so when someone poste something there is a very long loading and after some time there is a 524 error in the console.
If I reload the page, the new post is here but emails are not sent.

```
function send_email_to_all_users($activity_array, $activity_id) {
//get the post user's id 
    $username = bp_core_get_username( $activity_array['user_id']);
//get the link of the new post
    $view_link = bp_get_root_domain() . '/' . bp_get_activity_root_slug() . '/p/' . $activity_id;
//get every user but not the one who posted
    $users = BP_Core_User::get_users( array(
            'type' => 'alphabetical',
            'exclude' => array( $activity->user_id ),
        ) );
//for every user send an email
    foreach ( $users['users'] as $user ) {
        $to = $user->user_email;
           $subject = 'mail test subject';
            $message = $username .  " published <br> You can see " . $username . ', post here: ' . $view_link;
        
         wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
            
    }
}
add_action( 'bp_activity_add', 'send_email_to_all_users', 10, 4 );
```

When I tried with only one email it worked well

```
function send_email_to_all_users($activity_array, $activity_id) {
//get the post user's id 
    $username = bp_core_get_username( $activity_array['user_id']);
//get the link of the new post
    $view_link = bp_get_root_domain() . '/' . bp_get_activity_root_slug() . '/p/' . $activity_id;

   
        $to = 'test@mail.com';
           $subject = 'mail test subject';
            $message = $username .  " published <br> You can see " . $username . ', post here: ' . $view_link;
        
         wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
            
    
}
add_action( 'bp_activity_add', 'send_email_to_all_users', 10, 4 );
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Don't send 300 messages in the same request that creates the post. You'll want to return the request immediately, deferring the email sends until later by submitting a new job to a job queue. This way, the slow-to-process part will get run asynchronously in the background. The details about how to implement a job queue are pretty well beyond the scope of this question but you might start [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues).

Comment: In addition to comment by @alex you can use some plugin to create queue. here are some. - [mail queue plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/Mail+Queue/)

Comment: Thank you for your response ! I will try implementing a job queue then, thanks for the link !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

300 emails is not that many, unless you have 'weak' hosting or have a lot of concurrent activity posts.
Some hosting companies limit the number of emails that can be sent per day, per hour, etc. Ask your host.

The queue plugins may help, but you could speed up your filter function...

This is very inefficient for your needs: `$users = BP_Core_User::get_users...`

It gathers all kinds of thing you do not need. All you need are the email addresses. And the order does not matter.

All you need is the WP function [get_users](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/).

For example, something like this:

```
$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'user_email' ) ) );
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    $to = $user->user_email;
    //...etc
}
```

If you really need to prevent the author from receiving an email, get their email first:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user_email = $current_user->user_email;
```

And then use [unset](https://www.php.net/unset) to remove it from the `$users` array before you start the loop.

Answer (score 0):

For people having the same problem as me, here is an update.
As Alex Howansky and Anan suggested, I installed a queue plugin on wordpress.
I installed "Mail Queue" from WDM.
I also changed my code as shanebp suggested. I also contacted my host's support and it turns out that I had several configuration problems.
Now everything works perfectly, thanks for all your help !

Hope this can help!